# Problems in using middleware in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, middleware

I want to use middleware globally in a nestjs project.
for instance.

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

@Injectable()
export class SimpleLoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
   use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
      // do some tasks
      console.log('Executing request...');
      next();
   }
}
```

Then I try to use it in app,

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SimpleLoggerMiddleware } from './middleware';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(SimpleLoggerMiddleware);
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

It gives me an error

```
[Nest] 20784  - 06/27/2023, 2:58:45 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Class constructor SimpleMiddleware cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I don't know why I need a new here.

Ideas or solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the middleware class *instance* to `app.use`. You can only pass the class reference to a `consumer.apply()` call in a `NestModule`'s `configure` method. `app.use(new SimpleLoggerMiddleware())` should be fine

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of Middlewares in Nestjs (for instance), the common one [Middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#middleware) class, which you're trying to implement, this one should have a Nest instantiator (NestMiddleware from @nestjs/common) and a [functional middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#functional-middleware), which is a simple function working as Middleware.

That's the difference, one you instantiate as class, the other as function.

So, if you wanna use a common Middleware which more complex logic, needing more methods and dependencies, you should initialize it on the AppModule like this:

```js
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

@Injectable()
export class SimpleLoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
   use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
      // do some tasks
      console.log('Executing request...');
      next();
   }
}


/** app.module.ts */
/** All the modules imports above */
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(SimpleLoggerMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*'); // For all routes within your app.
  }
}
```

#### Note

**Is not a good practice** to instantiate the Common Middleware at the main.ts, because, if you have any dependency within the middleware, the providers are outside of the context container, if you were to instantiate with `app.use(new SimpleLoggerMiddleware(dependency1, dependency1, ..)` it would create another isolated context for those dependencies and stop working as singleton.

The other one

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export function simpleLoggerMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  next();
};

/** main.ts */
// ...
app.use(simpleLoggerMiddleware);
//...
```